# Can't Run Android application in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My problem is I can't run my Android application within Eclipse.

When I click run it shows me this form but there's no "Android Application" choice!

[image: picture]

Comment: you need to download and install the Android SDK if you want to use Eclipse. I'd recommend downloading and using [Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) however

Comment: This question is too vague. Please show some code, but only after you read what is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, when your posts are too short **do not** just copy and paste until it is accepted.

Comment: @smoggers With either IDE you need the SDK...

Answer (score 0):

If you must use Eclipse, you need to download the Android plugin for Eclipse. However, Google no longer supports this. In order to develop for the most recent version of Android you have to download Android Studio instead.